# Serialize only compile-time information

Tags: java, jackson

When serializing a Java object, because it utilizes reflection, Jackson serializes the object in it's runtime representation.

I have the following class:

```
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombokGetter
class ErrorInformation {

   private final Exception exception;
}
```

and

```
final ErrorInformation errorInfo = new ErrorInformation(new IllegalArgumentException("foo"));
```

Instead of just serializing an `Exception`, Jackson actually serializes all fields in an `IllegalArgumentException` - with uncontrollable consequences like cyclic references (see e.g. `mostSpecificCause` in `org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException`).

How can I tell Jackson to actually only serialize information of the `Exception`, with no regard of the actual runtime type, as you would expect from a statically typed language like Java?

Comment: This is how `Jackson` works - finds all `getters` and tries to serialise to `JSON`. This is default behaviour. If you don't want to see all extra details from this object you need to instruct `Jackson` what to hide and what can be serialised. What do you expect as result: exception message only?

Comment: @MichałZiober I know that that's how Jackson works. But that does not justify that it works this way. What I want is to serialize exactly all fields of the `Exception` class - because that's what I as a programmer am dealing with in this situation. If I were to require a specific class I would use generics instead.

Comment: "some maniac built the entire library using reflection" isn't exactly a nice thing to say for a super useful library like Jackson that you get to use for free.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek You're right, my bad. I edited my question. Though I still think it's not the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we cannot change `IllegalArgumentException` class logic, you can create additional instance field in your `ErrorInformation` class, populate it with information that you want to serialize and mark the `exception` variable as `transient`

e.g. Let's say you want to save the error message information. So, create a `String` field say `errorMessage` and populate it with the error message information in the constructor. Below is a sample code.

```
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombokGetter
class ErrorInformation {

   private final transient Exception exception;
   private final String errorMessage ;
   ErrorInformation(Exception exp) {
    this.exception = exp;
    this.errorMessage = exp.getMessage();
    }

}
```

At the time of de-serialization, you can use this error message information to create a similar(not same) instance of exception object which was serialized

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Jackson` by default serialises all `getters` method in given `POJO`. If we want to serialise `3-rd party` classes we need to take care about cycles and other problems. To do that we can use [`MixIn` feature](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations). We need to define that for all `NestedRuntimeException` exceptions we want to ignore `getMostSpecificCause` method.

```
interface NestedRuntimeExceptionMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore
    Throwable getMostSpecificCause();
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServerErrorException exception = new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error");
        ErrorInformation ei = new ErrorInformation(exception);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.addMixIn(NestedRuntimeException.class, NestedRuntimeExceptionMixIn.class);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ei));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
{
  "exception" : {
    "cause" : null,
    "stackTrace" : [ {
      "methodName" : "main",
      "fileName" : "JsonApp.java",
      "lineNumber" : 13,
      "className" : "JsonApp",
      "nativeMethod" : false
    } ],
    "rawStatusCode" : 500,
    "statusText" : "error",
    "responseHeaders" : null,
    "statusCode" : "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "responseBodyAsByteArray" : "",
    "responseBodyAsString" : "",
    "message" : "500 error",
    "rootCause" : null,
    "localizedMessage" : "500 error",
    "suppressed" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So kind of like blacklisting?

Comment: @MarkusAppel, Exactly. You need to explicitly tell `Jackson` do not look on this `getter`.

Comment: Then it does not answer my question.

Comment: @MarkusAppel, I understand, I thought you mean all fields from given exception not from `java.lang. Exception` only. In that case your `ErrorInformation` should have only fields you want to serialise and only them. So, in constructor or other static method like `ErrorInformation.from(e)` you need to copy all required properties and do not store `Exception` at all.

Comment: yeah, that's the only way I think. See @Ashishkumar Singh's answer.

Comment: @MarkusAppel, I saw it. So, you did create a simple `POJO` with only required `getters`. This is a classical `serialisation`/`deserialisation` problem how to work with `3-rd` party classes which are not normal `POJO`-s.